# Can't make cooldown work, bugs out and isn't working properly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

So I am making a VR game and what I want to do is, as soon as I press the trigger on the joystick the "sword" gets activated and can stay activated for 1 second, after that it has a cooldown of 1 second also in which it cannot get activated, and then it resets. I thought it would be simple but I can't for the life of me make it work.

Here's the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Valve.VR;

public class Sword : MonoBehaviour
{
    public SteamVR_Action_Boolean ActivateSword;
    public SteamVR_Input_Sources handType;
    private bool IsSwordActivated = false;
    private bool canSwordGetActivated = true;
    private bool cooldownStart = false;
    public Material activatedSword;
    public Material defaultSword;
    public float timeStamp;
    public float timer = 0;
    public float cooldown = 2;

    void Start()
    {
        ActivateSword.AddOnStateDownListener(TriggerDown, handType);
        ActivateSword.AddOnStateUpListener(TriggerUp, handType);
        timeStamp = Time.time;
    }

    public void TriggerUp(SteamVR_Action_Boolean fromAction, SteamVR_Input_Sources fromSource)
    {

            Debug.Log("Trigger is up");
            IsSwordActivated = false;
            this.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material = defaultSword;

    }
    public void TriggerDown(SteamVR_Action_Boolean fromAction, SteamVR_Input_Sources fromSource)
    {
        if (canSwordGetActivated == true)
        {
            Debug.Log("Trigger is down");
            IsSwordActivated = true;
            cooldownStart = true;
            this.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material = activatedSword;
        }


    }



    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Enemy"))
        {
            if (IsSwordActivated == true)
            {
                Destroy(collision.gameObject);
            }
        }

    }
    private void Update()
    {
        //if (timeStamp <= Time.time)
        //{
        //    if (IsSwordActivated == true)
        //    {
        //        timeStamp += 2;
        //        canSwordGetActivated = false;
        //        Debug.Log("test");
        //    }
        //}
        if (cooldownStart == true)
        {
            timer += Time.deltaTime;
            cooldown -= Time.deltaTime;
            if (timer >= 1f)
            {
                this.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material = defaultSword;
                IsSwordActivated = false;
                timer = 0;
            }
            if (timer == 0)
            {
                canSwordGetActivated = false;
            }
            if (cooldown <= 1f)
            {
                canSwordGetActivated = false;
            }
            if (cooldown <= 0)
            {
                cooldown = 2f;
                canSwordGetActivated = true;
                cooldownStart = false;
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: if(timer == 0) makes no sense, since it will only ever trigger when you go into the first if (timer >= 1f)

Answer (score 2):

You should not use `Update` but a [Coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) for that. Especially the "cooldown" should run independently from the "timer".

```
// Not needed
//private bool cooldownStart = false;
//public float timer = 0;

// reference this already via the Inspector if possible
[SerializeField] private MeshRenderer _meshRenderer;

[SerializeField] private float cooldownTime = 1;
[SerializeField] private float maxEnabledTime = 1;

// Otherwise get it only ONCE on runtime
private void Awake()
{
    if(!_meshRenderer) _meshRenderer = GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();
}

public void TriggerUp(SteamVR_Action_Boolean fromAction, SteamVR_Input_Sources fromSource)
{
    Debug.Log("Trigger is up");

    // stop the timeout
    StopAllCoroutines();

    // disable sword and start cooldown
    StartCoroutine(SwordCooldown());
}

public void TriggerDown(SteamVR_Action_Boolean fromAction, SteamVR_Input_Sources fromSource)
{
    if(IsSwordActivated) return;
    if (!canSwordGetActivated) return;

    Debug.Log("Trigger is down");

    // start timeout
    StartCoroutine(SwordEnabledTimer());
}

///<summary>
/// Disables sword and Runs cooldown before sword can be enabled again
///<summary>
private IEnumerator SwordCooldown()
{
    canSwordGetActivated = false;

    IsSwordActivated = false;
    _meshRenderer.material = defaultSword;

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(cooldownTime);

    canSwordGetActivated = true;
}

///<summary>
/// Disables the sword and jumps to cooldown after it was enabled for too long
///<summary>
private IEnumerator SwordEnabledTimer()
{
    canSwordGetActivated = false;

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(maxEnabledTime);

    StartCoroutine(SwordCooldown());
}
```

See [`WaitForSeconds`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitForSeconds.html)

---

Sideeffect/Advantage:

Coroutines are often better read- and maintainable and more flexible then polling states in `Update`!

For example You can now very simple extend both routines and add a progress display for both like e.g.

```
private IEnumerator SwordCooldown()
{
    canSwordGetActivated = false;

    IsSwordActivated = false;
    _meshRenderer.material = defaultSword;

    var timePassed = 0f;
    while(timePassed < cooldownTime)
    {
        var cooldownProgress = timePassed / cooldownTime;

        // do something with the cooldownProgress value 0-1

        timePassed += Mathf.Min(Time.deltaTime, cooldownTime - timePassed);
        yield return null;
    }

    canSwordGetActivated = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One simple way of doing this would be a coroutine:

```cs
class Sword {
   private bool isCoolingDown;

   public void Swing() {
       if (isCoolingDown) {
           Debug.Log("Sorry, cooling down right now");
           return;
       }

       StartCoroutine(DoSwingSword());

   }

   private IEnumerator DoSwingSword() {
       isCoolingDown = true;
       yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
       isCoolingDown = false;
   }
}
```

This will use a `bool` to track if you are in cooled down state and automatically reset this `bool` after one second, without you having to track `Time.deltaTime`. You can then wrap the rest of your logic around this `bool`.